# How can Steam Inventory items be shown from a private profile?

Tags: steam

There are a number of friends in our Steam group who prefer to keep their Steam profile private.

*(There are several reasons for this, which you can probably imagine. The excessive social media stats, and not really wanting to admit how much time you spent playing the past two weeks.)*

We would still like to trade Steam Inventory items with each other. Steam allows this, of course: we can blindly send items in our own inventory to friends, but we are unable to browse each other's inventory.

**Is there any way to only share certain things publicly:**

- library of games
- achievement showcase
- inventory
- *etc.*

**and keep other things private:**

- most recently played
- total time spent in-game
- *other social media-like stats*

Comment: I assume they don't want "friends only", and want full privacy?

Comment: @Riker Yes, that would be correct. Full privacy, even though we are friends in real life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter on Steam Community and click Edit Profile (as shown below):

[image]

Then go to confidentiality tab and change inventory settings accordingly and save (example below):

[image]

After that you will remain with a profile private, but others can see your inventory in the trade window.

Answer (score 1):

So there are some privacy settings you can access in steam.

First go to your profile
Then click on the edit profile button
On the right side of the page click on the "My Privacy Settings" tab
This will bring you to a menu with all of the privacy settings you have access to.

[image]

I think if you keep your profile private and set inventory to public, you will be able to see their inventory.

If this doesn't work then as far as I know you have to be friends with the person to be able to see a private profiles inventory